# If empty array value, console log something (not working)? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. I am trying to console.log 'empty array value' wherever the value is empty, however this isn't working properly. So what is the value of an empty array item and what can I set my if statement to (note:  if (statement[a].length === 0) does not work, as suggested in other stack overflow questions)

```
let statement = prompt("Say Something:");

statement = statement.split('');


for(a = 0; a < statement.length; a++){
  if(a === undefined){
    console.log('empty array value');
  }
} 

console.log(statement);
```

Comment: `a` is always a number, never `undefined`.

Comment: The `a` value is a number you are iterating with, so it will never be `undefined`. Further, the value of each element in the index will never be undefined. If you want to determine if the value entered into the prompt is nothing, just compare `statement === ''`. Not sure why you are splitting into a character array.

Comment: *"wherever the value is empty"* What is an "empty" value for you? Can you provide an example of the input and the expected output? See [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: Yes, and you could start with explaining what your prompt() function does - or even better provide the code. This could produce a string (most likely) or it could produce an empty string with a newline character at the end (possible), and how you test for "empty" will be greatly affected.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let statement = prompt("Say Something:");

statement = statement.split('');
   for(a = 0; a < statement.length; a++){
   if(statement[a].trim().length ==0){
     console.log('empty array value');
      }
   } 
console.log(statement);
```

**EDIT:**
your first problem is in your code that you try to check if `a` is undefined while `a` would never become undefined because it is is a number.

your second problem is that you had try `if (statement[a].length === 0)` wrongly because if your `statement[a]` contains spaces, it's length wont be zero while it is empty so you should `trim`  it first to remove all of spaces from the start and end of your element and after that check it's length( what i had posted it as a solution here)

Comment: This looks correct, but you should explain what you changed and why. People can learn more from your answer if you *explain* it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `a` will be never `undefined` because you are assigning `0` value to it in the `for` loop and it increments with every loop - **it is** defined and holds a value different than 'undefined'.

I guess you wanted to do it following way: `statement[a]`.

```js
let statement = prompt("Say Something:");

statement = statement.split('');

for(a = 0; a < statement.length; a++){
  if(statement[a] === undefined){
    console.log('empty array value');
  }
} 

console.log(statement);
```

Comment: While that's better, `statement[a]` will never be `undefined` because `statement` is an array of strings.

Comment: @FelixKling Exactly, but it just seem more logical than the previous version (while it still won't throw anything).

Comment: Sure, but will still never log to the console. Also the statement *"it is defined"* is a bit ambiguous (a *variable* can be defined (exist) but have the value `undefined`).

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
let statement = prompt("Say Something:");

statement = statement.split('');


for(a = 0; a < statement.length; a++){
  if(typeof a === "undefined"){
    console.log('empty array value');
  }
} 

console.log(statement);
```

Comment: `a` will always be a number, so `typeof a === "undefined"` is always `false`. Maybe if you explained your solution you would have noticed that it cannot work.